# What differentiates my closed question from this non-closed question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have a question here that was closed for asking "personal medical advice"
[Why does yawning sometimes cause intense pain at the base of my neck?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/15451/why-does-yawning-sometimes-cause-intense-pain-at-the-base-of-my-neck)

How is this one different? 
[Right wrist pain from using computer mouse](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/191/right-wrist-pain-from-using-computer-mouse?rq=1)

In both cases, a dude was describing a personal pain, and then asking for an explanation for it.

Comment: nothing.  It should have been closed too.  But that was 2015 when standards were perhaps looser than they are now.

Comment: Oh. Well then. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you referred to was asked about 3 days after the beta began, before we had completely hashed out the scope of the site. (And indeed, before we even had moderators).

While it may cause some confusion, there are still some of those questions around that should be closed as off topic/seeking personal advice, and indeed, I have closed the question.